# Build failing on Travis CI for simple Spring MVC app

Tags: apache, spring-mvc, tomcat, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have created a simple Spring MVC app and built and deployed using apache tomcat 7 on my localhost. The build for the same app is failing on Travis CI and the build log reads :

```
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/swarup-donepudi/BidToBuy.git swarup-donepudi/BidToBuy
Cloning into 'swarup-donepudi/BidToBuy'...
remote: Counting objects: 32, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
remote: Total 32 (delta 7), reused 28 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (32/32), 5.35 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7/7), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd swarup-donepudi/BidToBuy
$ git checkout -qf 4faeebe46b78137ea5676f49e2bf5224a8ffcb90
This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml
See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_76
0.92s$ ant deps
Buildfile: /home/travis/build/swarup-donepudi/BidToBuy/build.xml
BUILD FAILED
/home/travis/build/swarup-donepudi/BidToBuy/build.xml:87: /home/travis/build/swarup-donepudi/BidToBuy/C:/tomcat/lib does not exist.
Total time: 0 seconds
The command "ant deps" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

The build.properties file :

```
# Ant properties for building the springapp

appserver.home=C:/tomcat
# for Tomcat 5 use $appserver.home}/server/lib
# for Tomcat 6 use $appserver.home}/lib
appserver.lib=C:/tomcat/lib

deploy.path=C:/tomcat/webapps

tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8091/manager/text
tomcat.manager.username=tomcat
tomcat.manager.password=s3cret
```

Contents of .travis.yml file:

```
language: java
sudo: false
install: ant deps
```

I am assuming that the possible reason could be the path of the tomcat lib folder.

How does travis ci handle builds configured for tomcat server? I tried to find the answer but only to find none. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the path you have given is not valid for the Travis CI environment:

```
/home/travis/build/swarup-donepudi/BidToBuy/C:/tomcat/lib does not exist
```

As you are stating this in your properties file:

```
C:/tomcat
```

Take into account that Travis CI runs the build within a Linux Container, so you will have to explore other ways to deploy your application.

As you are using Spring, perhaps you should try Spring Boot, as it comes with an embedded Tomcat server, therefore freeing you from the build script.